# Logic concerning negative num inputs being converted to positive num inputs

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, negative-number, square-root

Maybe I'm asking google all the wrong questions but I scoured the internet and could not find posts similar to my unique problem.

This is a simple coding challenge from FreeCodeCamp:
I need to work on the **function abTest(a,b**) where when **a** OR **b** is less than **0**, the function will exit with the value of **undefined**. This is because we run the value **a** and **b** through a square root function. And you cannot take the square root of a negative number. Below is the code.

```js
// Setup
function abTest(a, b) {
 
  if (a < 0) {
    a = -a;
   return undefined;
} else if (b < 0) {
    b = -b;
    return undefined;
}

  return Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2));
}

// Change values below to test your code
abTest(2,2);
```

This code I used above works fine. However I have to specify that when **a** or **b** is **< 0**,  **a** is assigned **-a** and **b** is assigned **-b**. *Why is this necessary?* In addition I want to convert this into a Switch statement, but I run into this problem of negative num values. **Below** are two switch statements I wrote but when using negative num input the **abTest(-2,2)** or **abTest(2,-2)** does not return the value **undefined**.

**My First Switch Statement**

```js
switch (a,b) {
    case a<0 || b<0:
      return undefined;
  }
```

**My Second Switch Statement**

```js
  switch (a,b) {
    case a < 0: 
      a = -a;
      console.log(undefined);
      break;
    case b < 0: 
      b = -b;
      console.log(undefined);
      break;
  }
```

Where is this hole in my logic concerning switch statements and negative num values?

Thank you guys,

Comment: `switch(a, b)` ignores `a` and only checks `b` because `,` is the comma operator and `switch` is not to be used as a function. There can be only one variable there. Also `case`s don’t work like `if` statements; you can’t put conditions there, you need to put values there.

Comment: There’s no reason to use a `switch` for this. `if (a < 0 || b < 0) return undefined;`.

Comment: Ok, but concerning the logic behind the if and else statement. Why and where is my negative num input being converted back to a positive num? Or is the nature of the language and I will have to always assign a number below 0 as negative?

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to convert a = -a unless there is something wrong with freecodecamp. Just returning the value of undefined would/should produce the exact same result as changing a variable and then still returning undefined. To simplify your code you could also combine the if and else if statements like so

```
function abTest(a, b) {

if (a < 0 || b < 0){
  return undefined;
} else {
  return Math.round(Math.pow(Math.sqrt(a) + Math.sqrt(b), 2));
 }
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: ah much simpler and worked fine in freecodecamp.  Thank you,